# Como saber si una variable me trae datos en symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony4

Trabajo con symfony 4 tengo el siguiente codigo

```
public function mallaCuadroCalificaciones(\Knp\Snappy\Pdf $knpSnappyPdf, Aula $aula)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $aulaDetalle = $em->getRepository(Aula::class)->getAulaDetail($aula);
    $distributivos = $aulaDetalle->getDistributivos();
    $matriculados = $aulaDetalle->getMatriculados();
    $listaCalificaciones = $aulaDetalle->getMatriculados()->getCalificaciones();
```

Como saber si la variable `$listaCalificaciones` me trae datos, como lo puedo depurar?

Estoy trabajando con el IDE Visual Studio Code

Como saber si la variable

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es la que debería estar almacenando dicha variable?

Comment: var_dump($listaCalificaciones);

Comment: @BetaM un array, en donde me muestra lo que trae la lista, alguna ventana? donde lo visualizo?

Comment: Entonces puedes hacer uso del método `count` de PHP o del `var_dumper` de Symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar dd($listaCalificaciones);exit; o var_dump($listaCalificaciones);

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la funcion [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) para determinar si la variable contiene datos o no o como tambien fue sugerida, la function [count](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php).

Comment: james_bond, mi problema es como visualizarlo, vengo de C# del ide Visual Studio, y me muestra ventanas para ver los resultados de los break point que pongo en el codigo, Ahora en Visual Studio Code donde lo visualizo si esta vacio o si no contiene elementos, estoy trabajando en una api